# Como estructurar Switch Case en Dart?

Tags: dart, switch

La idea es que el usuario ingrese su nombre a traves de un Textfield y comparar el nombre con los case presentados, dependiendo del nombre que ingrese lo direccionara a ventanas diferentes, en Dart

```
    _navegacionVentana(data) {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    final String nombre= "asesor";
    //void main(List<String> args) {
    //var nombre = "asesor";

    switch (nombre) {
      case "asesor":
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    ListaChat()));
        //}
        break;
      case "asesorz":
        print("asesork");
        //}
        break;

      default:
        // {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Chat(
                    )));
      //}
      // break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: [Aquí](https://gist.github.com/axl0d/841e3da1258dc6edc9d71a0168cb6782#file-navigate_to_page-dart) hice un pequeño ejercicio donde puedes ver la funcionalidad que requieres espero te sirva, lo puedes probar en [DartPad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/)

Comment: @axlod , Si exacto, asi le tenia y si funciona, ya   pero después implemente el If Else y con este condicionante funciono mucho mejor, Gracias